# Consulta java sql

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Estoy programando con Java. Soy nuevo en este lenguaje. Lo que pasa es que hago un insert a una tabla en MySQL, pero me aparece:

> SQLException: Unknown column 'jose' in 'field list'

De hecho, imprimí el SQL y lo ejecuté en el PhpAdmin y funciona. ¿Saben por qué pasa esto? Abajo les dejo el código.

```
 private void btn_ingresarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
 /* Insumo obj= new Insumo();
obj.setDescripcion(txtrut.getText());
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj.getDescripcion());*/
String name=txtrut.getText();
String pass=jPasswordField1.getText();
String sql="INSERT INTO usuario values(1,"+name+","+pass+")";
  try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 System.out.println("Registro exitoso");

} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println(e.toString());

   }

    Connection con= null;

try {

      con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ropa_trabajo?"
        + "user=root&password=");

// Otros y operaciones sobre la base de datos...
 Statement sentencia=con.createStatement();
sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

// Mantener el control sobre el tipo de error
 System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());

}

    System.out.println(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error sucede porque al concatenar tus variables directamente a la cadena SQL:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO usuario values(1,"+name+","+pass+")";
```

... el SQL resultante no incluye las comillas simples alrededor de los valores. Probablemente, el insert resulta en algo parecido a:

```
INSERT INTO usuario values(1,jose,password)
```

Como `jose` no está rodeado de comillas simples, MySQL asume que `jose` es el nombre de una columna.

Por supuesto, pudieras agregar las comillas que faltan. Pero la verdadera solución es de usar un `PreparedStatement` y usar parámetros.

Ejemplo:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO usuario values(1,?,?)";
PreparedStatement sentencia = con.prepareStatement(sql);
sentencia.setString(1, name);
sentencia.setString(2, pass);
sentencia.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia pero lo que esta esta en el insert son signos de interrogacion. como funciona, me sale error de sintaxis

Comment: SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
INSERT INTO usuario values(1,?,?)

Comment: ya me funciono, tenia en el executeupdate tambien la variable sql, una consulta si quiero imprimir el sql pero que me aparezcan los parametros en vez de signos de interrogacion como se hace.

Comment: por cierto muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente para ver el SQL sin los signos de interrogación: `System.out.println(sentencia);`.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta linea de código

```
String sql="INSERT INTO usuario values(1,"+name+","+pass+")";
```

Por esta:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO usuario values(1,'"+name+"','"+pass+"')";
```

*Nota: Agregue comillas simples a tus variables. Es un regla SQL para insertar `varchar/texto/cadenas/caracteres` (como prefieras llamarlo).